# Minimum Jars needed for a jms client application

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Which set of jar are needed for a java JMS client application,  to publish the message. 
I have **activemq-client-5.13.3.jar**, on my class path.  but Its not enough and getting

```
'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
javax/management/j2ee/statistics/Stats'.
```

Note :- while adding **'activemq-all'** jar. It will work fine but I dont want to add these multiple jar because it is around 17MB.

```
 Connection connection = null;

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Topic topic = session.createTopic("customerTopic");

        connection.start();

        String payload = "Important task";
        Message msg = session.createTextMessage(payload);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);
        producer.send(msg);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        session.close();

        if(connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to find out is to use maven with the ActiveMQ [source code](https://github.com/apache/activemq) checkout out from git.  Move to the activemq-client project folder and ask maven to generate the dependency tree `mvn dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:bundle:5.15.10-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] +- javax.jmdns:jmdns:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:test
[INFO]    \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:runtime
```

In your case you could switch to the release tag for 5.13.3 to get the exact list although I don't think it has changed much since that release.  Of course if you build your project using maven then you can do it from your project dir as well and it'd give you the dependency tree for your complete project.

Comment: I am agree with your answer and just want to know one more information that is there any way to disable these jars dependency. because i am compiling my above code only using activemq-client jar and geronimo-jms_1.1_spec jar. I just want to exclude other dependency jar if possible.

Comment: If you don't care about it working you can remove them all, otherwise your success or failure depends on what your code does given that it you hit a code path that uses one of those libs an it isn't there then things will likely go boom.